# How do you define an ordered pair in Coq?

Tags: coq

I am a programmer, but an ultra-newbie to Coq, and have tried to figure out the tutorials without much success.  My question is very simple:  How does one define an ordered pair (of natural numbers) in Coq?

Here was my attempt:

```
Variable node1 : nat.
Variable node2 : nat.
Inductive edge : type := node1 -> node2.
```

(Note that "edge" is the name I am using for ordered pair.)  The third line gives a syntax error, suggesting that I need a '.' in the sentence somewhere.

I don't know what to do.  Any help would be great!  (Also, is there a tutorial that helps teach very basic Coq concepts better than the ones that are easily seen given a Google search for "Coq Tutorial" ?)

Comment: The natural solution would be to simply use a tuple: `nat * nat`.  In reality, you probably want a sigma type that says something about well formed-ness to a certain graph.

Comment: So an inductive?  "Inductive edge : type : nat * nat." doesn't work either.

Comment: It's just a `Definition` in the case, you're applying the `*` constructor.  You should find a better intro Coq tutorial, as it would explain this :-).  The book CoqArt would be a good place to start

Comment: I don't think that works, I think * is for nats.

Comment: It needs to be `type` scope for `*` to be interpreted properly.  `Definition t := (nat * nat) % type.`

Comment: That worked...thanks.  You could post it as an answer.  Also, thanks for the suggestion on the book....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this simply enough by just using a Coq definition:

```
Definition ordered_pair := (nat * nat) % type.
```

This introduces `ordered_pair` as a synonym for `(nat * nat) % type` (note that the `% type` is required to get Coq to interpret `*` in the scope of types, rather than naturals).  The real power is in the use of `*`:

```
Inductive prod (A B:Type) : Type :=
  pair : A -> B -> prod A B.
```

(From http://coq.inria.fr/stdlib/Coq.Init.Datatypes.html)

You get all the necessary elimination principles, etc... from there.